# Why can't I clear the background property (wpf control)

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

Why does clearing the background using the following method

```
txb.Background.ClearValue(Control.BackgroundProperty);
```

give an exception of

> "cannot clear background properties on object '#FFFFFFFF' because it
>   is in a read-only state"

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.Background` is not required. It should be:

```
txb.ClearProperty(Control.BackgroundProperty);
```